# Style wont apply until refresh HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue with trying to customize the default Video-player. I'm using js/css from videojs.com.

In the header of my Index.html I have the following code:

```
<link type="text/css" href="CSS/video-js-6.2.7/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="CSS/video-js-6.2.7/video.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .vjs-default-skin {
        color: #232a3a;
    }

    .vjs-default-skin .vjs-play-progress,
    .vjs-default-skin .vjs-volume-level {
        background-color: #9cbaca
    }

    .vjs-default-skin .vjs-control-bar,
    .vjs-default-skin .vjs-big-play-button {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7)
    }

    .vjs-default-skin .vjs-slider {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2333333333333333)
    }

    .vjs-default-skin .vjs-control-bar {
        font-size: 94%
    }
</style>
```

When I load the page I get the browsers default styling, this stays until i press F5 and refreshes the site, then the new correct look shows up.

I'm guessing that the CSS is not fully loaded or something like that. It then works until I clear the cache, but I would really like it to work on the first load also.

Comment: Why don't you directly overwrite the properties you want in the *video-js.css* file ?

Comment: @Louis 'LYRO' Dupont That's generally a bad idea to directly edit library files.

Comment: @Louis'LYRO'Dupont since it's not "my" css I like to have control of what changes I have done myself :)

Comment: What happens if you put the `<style>...</style>` tag before the `<script>` ?

Comment: @TimothéMalahieude You can import a CSS file just after the librairy to overwrite some of the rules.

Comment: Yep, I was answering to Louis 'LYRO' Dupont

Comment: @TimothéMalahieude No effect, same also if I just remove those tags

Comment: @TimothéMalahieude This is better than loading style values multiple times for the same element.
I would recommand you to comment out the library code and add yours directly.